# JUST_IN_TIME cache type Probabilistic selection

Tags: optaplanner

In the documentation it is clearly stated that cacheType JUST_IN_TIME does not work with Probabilistic selection.Since most of my moves are generated "just in time" is there some way that i can use these two together? If there isn't, what are some other options to use?

Comment: Why do you want to use probabilistic selection? Please explain the use case to give an idea what alternatives could match.

Comment: I want to apply different probabilities for the moves i have. Since I have many combined in a single UnionSelector, certain useful moves are less commonly tried than other moves.  This seems to be because some moves are rejected due to built-in constraints and because some of the moves are very similar to each other.

Comment: Also why doesn't JUST_IN_TIME work with Probabilistic selection? I've been wondering about that since i read it on the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i found what i was looking for with the `fixedProbabilityWeight` which let's me manually configure from start what moves will be used more than others. On top of that i found the `SelectionProbabilityWeightFactory<NurseRoster, IterableSelector>` interface that let's me modify the probabilityWeight while solving.